# table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "infobox ww_ib ww_ib_1" }) is not working

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to parse the table given at this location: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz"
The property table is identified as the class = infobox ww_ib ww_ib_1.
I am expecting to obtain the values given in the table such as:
'Category, Oxide, Chemical formula etc..."
However, the table returns a None type. 
Could someone please help me?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
wiki = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = requests.get(wiki,headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "infobox ww_ib ww_ib_1" })
print (table)
```

Please do let me know if you know of better ways to scrape wikipedia!

Comment: And your expected output? No hints of that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what the problem was. The class of the table is just 'infobox' and not 'infobox ww_ib ww_ib_1"